# Displaying multiple data with different date using PHP and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem on getting multiple data of a single patient. I can only generate 1 physical examination result and I can't get all of it.

My Controller

```
public function print_sum_report($case_id){
    //fetching all data from different tables
    $case_id = 1;
    $postnatal_id = 1;
    $this->load->model('Prms_model');
    $data['n_status'] = $this->Prms_model->get_status_f($case_id);
    $data['n_mh'] = $this->Prms_model->get_mh_f($case_id);
    $data['n_pe'] = $this->Prms_model->get_pe_f($case_id);
    $data['n_post'] = $this->Prms_model->get_pn_f($postnatal_id);
    $data['n_infant'] = $this->Prms_model->get_infant_f($case_id);
    $this->load->view('report/reportsum', $data);
    // print_r($data);
  }
```

My Model

```
 public function get_pe_f($case_id){
    // joining 2 tables (physicalexamination and patient_info by ID)
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('physicalexamination');
    $this->db->where('case_id', $case_id);
    $this->db->join('patient_info', 'patient_info.patient_ID = physicalexamination.Patient_ID');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: is it possible to use a condition to get all result from different date in foreach?

Comment: Can u show part of ur schema?, at least the ids and relations on the related tables?

Comment: I cant post the screenshot but these are the primary and foreign keys. For this table (physical examination) the foreign key is Num and both patient_id and case_id are foreign keys.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the query, maybe (but i'll show u an error is so) its `patient_info.patient_ID = physicalexamination.Patient_ID` , maybe the letters case on `Patient_ID`, or in the view u are not looping the array correctly, try `foreach($this->db->result() as $row){ echo $row->field;}  or  echo $this->db->result()->num_rows() ` to check the ammount of rows in your query, or try remove `select('*')`, its not necesarry when u are calling all the fileds, and add `->get_compiled_select()` it will show u the query that is executing in the db.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll it.

Comment: patient_info.patient_ID = physicalexamination.Patient_ID

In physicalexamination's column it is in Patient_ID but in relation its patient_ID

Comment: forgot to tell u, if u want to check the select script that the db driver is running, the query should be `$query = $this->db->from(...)->where(..)->join(...)->get_compiled_select(); echo $query;`

Answer (score 0):

$data['n_pe'] is a result object which contains many rows. You need to iterate over it to gather all the rows:

```
foreach($data['n_pe'] as $pe) {
    var_dump($pe);
}
```

Also, you could write your model this way:

```
 public function get_pe_f($case_id) {

    // joining 2 tables (physicalexamination and patient_info by ID)
    return $this->db
        ->where('case_id', $case_id)
        ->join('patient_info', 'patient_info.patient_ID = physicalexamination.Patient_ID');
        ->get('physicalexamination')
        ->result();
 }
```